# Where does the value of entity come from in a field of a content type?

Tags: 8, entities

Where does the value of entity come from in a field of a content type?

I am trying to understand how the property (if it is a property) entity is related to the field.

This question is more informative, I describe my case below.

I have a type of content **News**, in this I added field of type **image** called **"field_image"** with a limit of a **single** value.

Type of content: News
Field: field_image

**Debuggin:**

I programmatically load the node:

```
// Return Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
$node = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage("node")->load(1);

// {\Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList}
kint($node->field_image);

// {Drupal\file\Entity\File}
kint($node->field_image->entity); // from where comes from entity?
```

From the last example I show above **($node->field_image->entity)**, where does the property entity appear, how can field_image access it and know that it is a file type field?

I'm just trying to understand these internal Drupal relationships.
Thank you very much for helping me understand this.
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's literally magic (well, [PHP magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) anyway).

[`FieldItemBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemBase.php/8.6.x) implements `__get()`, which will respond to any property on the object (existing or not):

```
public function __get($name) {
  // There is either a property object or a plain value - possibly for a
  // not-defined property. If we have a plain value, directly return it.
  if (isset($this->properties[$name])) {
    return $this->properties[$name]->getValue();
  }
  elseif (isset($this->values[$name])) {
    return $this->values[$name];
  }
}
```

And the image field type extends the entity reference field type, which maintains an `entity` property (see [`EntityReferenceItem::propertyDefinitions`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21EntityReferenceItem.php/function/EntityReferenceItem%3A%3ApropertyDefinitions/8.6.x)).

So when you request the non-existent `entity` property on the field class, `FieldItemBase` hooks it up for you via the `$properties` array, and you get an entity back.